# How to handle incomplete stripe connected account onboarding?

Tags: stripe-payments

I am after the best practice for handling incomplete stripe connected account onboarding.

When onboarding goes smoothly, everything is simple. But there are fiddly edgecases everywhere, which results in a lot of permutations of values for account [`requirements`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-requirements)

These include

- `current_deadline`
- `currently_due`
- `disabled_reason`
- `errors`
- `eventually_due`
- `past_due`
- `pending_verification`

This creates a lot of complexity.

I need a simple way to:

1. figure out if the connected user needs to be notified of something (i.e. that they need to give more info), and
2. what to tell them.

My current strategy is to check if `errors` is empty, and if not, simply display them along with a link to manage the user's stripe account so they can address the errors.

But I'm worried this strategy will miss things (perhaps minor things that could be addressed *before* they become errors).

**TL;DR** I suspect most users will onboard without any problem, but for the few who do have issues, I want to ensure the app notifies them that they need to address them. What is the best way to do this? (using the information in `requirements` or other info)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When handling identity verification manually using the API, a simple way to check whether your connected user might need to be notified to provide more info is to look at the [`charges_enabled`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-charges_enabled) and [`payouts_enabled`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-payouts_enabled) properties on the user's account object. If either of these two properties are `false` then you might need to reach out to the connected user for more information.

In cases where the connected user's charges and payouts are disabled, you would use the [disabled_reason](https://stripe.com/docs/api/accounts/object#account_object-requirements-disabled_reason) property on the requirements hash to learn the reason why charges and/or payouts are disabled. The possible disabled reasons are all documented [here](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/identity-verification-api#determining-if-identity-or-business-verification-is-needed), but I'll list them out nonetheless:

- `action_required.requested_capabilities` You need to request
  capabilities for the connected account. For details, see Request and
  unrequest capabilities.
- `requirements.past_due` Additional verification
  information is required to enable payout or charge capabilities on
  this account.
- `requirements.pending_verification` Stripe is currently
  verifying information on the connected account.
- `rejected.fraud` Account is rejected due to suspected fraud or illegal activity.
- `rejected.terms_of_service` Account is rejected due to suspected terms
  of service violations.
- `rejected.listed` Account is rejected because
  it's on a third-party prohibited persons or companies list (such as
  financial services provider or government).
- `rejected.other` Account is rejected for another reason.
- `listed` Account might be on a prohibited persons or companies list (Stripe will investigate and either reject or reinstate the account appropriately).
- `under_review` Account is under review by Stripe.
- `other` Account isn't rejected but is disabled for another reason while being reviewed.

Using the `disabled_reason`, you can assess whether the user needs to be notified with a request for more information (i.e., `requirements.past_due`), whether they need to be notified for another reason (e.g., `rejected.listed`), or whether you need to make programmatic changes to the user's Stripe account (e.g., `action_required.requested_capabilities`).